# Batch File looping until certain text is displayed

Tags: loops, batch-file, icacls

Currently have a batch file for replacing NTFS permissions using the takeown and icacls commands, i have added these commands to a loop and it works great.

Is there a way to exit the loop when a certain response is displayed? like "Failed processing 0 files" or something like that? the code i am using is below, hopefully this will help some other people also.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%x in (1,1,1000) do (

    echo Taking ownsership of Folders & Files - loop %%x
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('takeown.exe /R /A /F "F:\Shares\NetBackup Clients" /D N ^| findstr /i /C:"Failed processing 0 files"') do (
        set "error=%%i"
        if "!errorlevel!"=="0" goto :end
    )

    echo Applying permissions to filestore - loop %%x
    icacls.exe "F:\Shares\NetBackup Clients" /grant "Domain\Group":F /grant "Domain\Group":R /T /C

    echo Finished applying permissions to filestore - loop %%x >> C:\Loopy.txt
)
goto :eof
:end
echo %error%
```

Many Thanks

Comment: Check the condition with an `if` and `goto :label` outside the for (code block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might have the error the wrong way around, so you would need to adjust it accordingly, but we use `findstr` and if we meet the requirement (`errorlevel` is `0`) we exit the loop.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /l %%x in (1,1,1000) do (
    echo %%x
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('takeown.exe /R /A /F "\\fileserver\share\" /D N ^| findstr /i "Failed processing 0 files"') do (
        set "error=%%i"
        if "!errorlevel!"=="0" goto :end
    )
    echo Finished takeown >> C:\Loopy.txt
    icacls.exe "\\fileserver\share\" /grant "Domain\Group":F /grant "Domain\Group":R /T /C
    echo Finished icacls >> C:\Loopy.txt
    echo Loop %%x >> C:\Loopy.txt
)
goto :eof
:end
echo %error%
```

Comment: Yes thank you for this, the takeown command should be in the inside loop! but this is great! thanks very much! really helped.

Comment: Sorry i may have confused things, the takeown command produces the text that the loop needs to exit from. after there are "Failed processing 0 files" then i will run a icacls command one last time manually.  So it goes takeown -> icacls -> takeown -> icacls -> takeown etc until the text is displayed from the takeown command. sorry

Comment: then just replace the `icacls` command string in the loop with the takedown process.. i.e `for /f "delims=" %%i in ('takedown...)...`

Comment: edited answer to demonstrate what I mean.. you would need to modify and test as I cannot replicate the environment.

Comment: I have done this but the process does not seem to exit it just starts loop again.

Comment: Ahh so i dont need to use the findstr?

Comment: Yes this is what i have now, but still loops round

Comment: is the findstr string exactly as `Failed processing 0 files` you need to verify that string is correct else it will not match.. or better, do you want to only catch the error containing `failed`? that would be easier..

Comment: `processed file: F:\Shares\NetBackup Clients\7.7.3\x64\Symantec NetBackup.msi
processed file: F:\Shares\NetBackup Clients\7.7.3\x64\VxLogServer.exe
processed file: F:\Shares\NetBackup Clients\7.7.3\x64\VxSetup.ini
Successfully processed 475 files; Failed processing 0 files
Started taking ownership loop 8`

Comment: Yes that works but it must be only failed at 0 files as that will be the end of the loop.

Comment: Nope it just keeps looping

Comment: Please add `echo EL !errorlevel!` before `set "error=%%i"` and let me know the errorlevel number it returns.

Comment: I have added it in the line above "set "error=%%i"" and it produces nothing to screen.

Comment: it is then not issuing that for loop it seems. Can you please edit your question and post exact script as it now.?

Comment: oh.. an just try something else.. from the finstr command, remove this `/C:` I did so in the answer already.